# Scrapy scraping content of td with multiple td's of same class

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the content of a table, which contains multiple rows and data which have the same class. This is the website: http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/323351/crucial-ballistix-tactical-blt2c4g3d1608et3lx0ceu/specificaties/

So my goal is to scrape the brand name : Crucial, from the table class spec-detail

this is the HTML, the tr's all have the same class so it's impossible to select with class.

```
     <div id="tab:specificaties" class="tab_active">

<table class="spec-detail">
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="spec-index-column"></td>
            <td class="spec-column">
                <a href="http://tweakers.net/merk/306/crucial/">

                    Crucial

                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="spec-index-column">

                Serie

            </td>
            <td class="spec-column">
                <a href="http://tweakers.net/serie/2930/ballistix-tactical/"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my code:

```
items = []
            sel = Selector(response)
            products = sel.xpath('//div[@id="tab:specificaties"]')
            category = sel.xpath('//li[@id="tweakbaseBreadcrumbCategory"]/a/text()').extract()
            print(category)
            for product in products:
                if 'Geheugen intern' in category:
                    item = Memory()
                    item['Category'] = category
                    item['Brand'] = ''.join(product.xpath('//tr[contains(td[1], "Merk")]/td[2]/a/text()').extract())
                    items.append(item)
```

Which returns

```
CrucialCrucialCrucial
```

I've also tried

```
sel.xpath('//*[@id="tab:specificaties"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a/text()')
```

This however returned nothing.

The selection probably matches multiple elements on the page, and i can't find a way to seperate them.  How can i make this return "Crucial" 1 time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localize the xpath to the specific product by putting a `dot` before it:

```
product.xpath('.//tr[contains(td[1], "Merk")]/td[2]/a/text()')
```

Demo:

- before

  ```
  >>> for product in products:
  ...     print product.xpath('//tr[contains(td[1], "Merk")]/td[2]/a/text()').extract()
  ... 
  [u'Crucial', u'Crucial', u'Ballistix Tactical', u'Crucial']
  ```
- after

  ```
  >>> for product in products:
  ...     print product.xpath('.//tr[contains(td[1], "Merk")]/td[2]/a/text()').extract()
  ... 
  [u'Crucial']
  ```

Comment: I just put a dot there and it gives the error, "Invalid XPath //tr[]".

Comment: @jjerryy are you sure you are using the same xpath that I've provided in the answer?

Comment: Nevermind it works, seemed like there was a different part of the code that was wrong. Thank you